# Assign value error in xcode/swift

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to call a value that is stored in a ProfilesAPI file and use it in one of my views and am getting an error stating " Cannot assign value of 'String?' to type 'Float!' ". Is there a way to convert either one of these so I get rid of the error. My code:

```
var ratePerMin: Float!

ProfilesAPI.apiV1ProfilesGet({ (data, error) in
        if let profile = data {
            if profile.rate == nil {
                self.ratePerMin = 0.00
            }
            else {
                self.ratePerMin = profile.rate
            }

        }
        self.updateRatePerMin()
})
```

The error is coming in on the line "self.ratePerMin = profile.rate

Comment: You might be well advised to switch `var ratePerMin: Float!` to `var ratePerMin: Float?` if you're dealing with APIs, parsing, or other fallible  situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign a String to a Float. You need to *coerce* the String *into* a Float. Try this:

```
self.ratePerMin = Float(profile.rate!)
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, I'm still getting the same error. I'm kind of a newbie to swift/xcode so I'm not super familiar with programming rules etc.

Comment: I think if you replace `self.ratePerMin = profile.rate` with the code I gave, you will _not_ get the same error.

Comment: you are correct, I had it pasted in wrong, got rid of my error thank you!